# Doctrine replace associations with their ids

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle

I'm building an API using `FOSRestBundle` in `Symfony2` and I'm trying to remove the entity associations from an entity with no luck, to minimize the JSON data sent in the API response.

```
public function helperRemoveAssociations($entities) {

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $data = array();

    /** @var WBEntity $entity */
    foreach ($entities as $entity) {

        $entityAssociations = $entity->getAssociationNames($em); // ex: array('category', 'comments')

        foreach ($entityAssociations as $associationName) {

            $associationGetter = 'get' . ucfirst($associationName);
            $associationSetter = 'set' . ucfirst($associationName);

            /** @var WBEntity $associationObject */
            $associationObject = $entity->$associationGetter();
            $associationId = $associationObject->getEntityId($em); // ex: 51

            $entity->$associationSetter($associationId); // I am not allowed to write an integer 
        }

        $data[] = $entity;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

How can I accomplish this, replacing the associated entities with their respective ids.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding this you should be handling this in our serialization process by filtering the properties (in this case certain related entities) you are actually going to serialize.

Comment: Never used `FOSRestBundle` before, but I guess you should _convert_ relationships to ids at the time you serialize your entities into JSON - your function looks very _hacky_ to me! Your entity has a relationship to another  entity, and you should not change that. If you want to change the JSON output, you should change the way you output your JSON, not your entities...

Comment: @prodigitalson: You're right, I missed the serialization exclusion annotations. http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies

Comment: @MikO: You're right too, what I was doing it was pretty hacky, but at the moment it was my only option, since I had no access to the serialization process. That's why I tried to remove the entities associations before the serialization takes place. Thank you!